# How do I get Sublime Text 2 package manager to use my proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, sublimetext2, sublimetext, ubuntu-12.04

I have to work through a proxy at the office and when I press (Ctrl+Shift+P), type Install and try to load a package list, I get the error "Package Control: There are no packages available for installation."

In my 'Package Control.sublime-settings' I have:

```
{
    "auto_upgrade_last_run": 1345569476,
    "http_proxy": "http://user_name:password@<proxy-name>:<proxy_port>"
}
```

What am I missing OR what is a better option for me to control my system using the proxy. Once I get home I typically have to disable these proxies. Is there a truly system-wide way to make it use a proxy and then disable the proxy with a single command or click?

Also this is in Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: Sublime Text Package Manager has been updated to include options for working through a proxy, you can find this in the package settings.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need the `http://` part. For example:

```
"http_proxy": "proxy.my.net:8080",
"https_proxy": "proxy.my.net:8080",
```

At least, this works for me, on Ubuntu and on Windows also.

Answer (score 1):

The first time, I was able to sort out problems with Package Manager by using HTTP instead of HTTPS, as in

http://alensiljak.blogspot.co.at/2012/11/setting-up-portable-sublime-text-2.html

The default setup seem to respect the system proxy settings and work through the proxy without explicitely setting "http_proxy", "proxy_username", and "proxy_password".

Hopefully this helps.

More details on various settings at (for the record, as you've already referred to these):

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/settings

Note: This applies to Windows version. I keep the Linux version in the same directory but can't confirm the behaviour currently.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following in `Package Control.sublime.settings` worked for me on Windows 7.

`{
    "auto_upgrade_last_run": 1345569476,
    "http_proxy": "user_name:password@<proxy-name>:<proxy_port>"
}`

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was changing the user_agent in Package Control settings, by default is sublime text specific user_agent, but changing it to (for example) the Firefox user_agent, worked for me.

Comment: the proxy at my workplace only allows certain user agents, doing this made package control work for me. thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something obvious that you've tried, but probably worth checking: do you have http_proxy set in your OS environment?

Answer (score 0):

If above answer did not work, I fix it by following steps:

1. open your Internet Explorer
2. tools →internet options→ advanced tag→ Security → Cancel the checkbox "Check for Server Certificate revocation"    .
3. Restart your Sublime Text

Hope it can help you.